# Should I free long-lived memory that would normally be freed at the very end of the program?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am currently writing a library that parse some structured binary data into a set of objects. These objects are expected to outlive any user code, and would normally be freed at the end or after the main function.

I am using shared (and weak) pointers to manage the memory of each object, but it is causing a lot of added complexity to the program, and raises structural issues that I will not get into in this particular question.

Considering that:

- traversing the entirety of the binary data is expensive and I cannot afford to do it more than one time,
- each visited entry is used to build an object, that then gets registered (i.e. added into the set),
- entries in the binary data may rely on other entries that appears later but gets parsed immediately, and registered when the entry is visited again,
- duplicate entries may appear at any moment, but I need to merge those duplicates into one instance (and update any pointer referencing those duplicates to the new merged entry) before registration,
- every single one of those objects is guaranteed to be of one of many POD types deriving a common class, so nothing except memory needs to be cleaned up,
- the resulting program will run on a modern OS (or in this case, that collects memory from dead processes),

I am very tempted to just use raw pointers, never free the memory taken by those objects and let the OS do its cleanup after the process exits.

What would be the best course of action?

Comment: It is not obvious from your question why you are allocating objects dynamically at all. Is there a good reason why you can't just put the POD types in a container directly?

Comment: @ChrisDrew ah, yes, I did not mention that all of these objects are of various types (although inheriting from a common base class), so I need to store pointers rather than actual objects.

Comment: A POD type can't have a virtual destructor and without that you can't delete it using a pointer-to-base.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're writing reusable code, you need to at least provide the option of cleaning up.  What if some program uses your library for one operation, and then continues running?  It's not safe to assume that the process exits immediately after your library's task is complete.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers cover the general and standard approach: in an ideal world, yes, you'd clean up your memory, because it makes the code more generic and more reusable and helps with tooling.  As others have said, `std::unique_ptr` for owning pointers and raw pointers for non-owning pointers should work well.

There are a couple of more specialized approaches that may or may not be useful:

- Use a pool allocator (such as [Boost.Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/pool/doc/html/index.html), or roll your own) to allocate a bunch of memory up front then dole out pieces of it for your objects. You can then free every object at once by deleting the pool.
- Intentionally not freeing memory is occasionally a valid technique. See, e.g., ["Increasing Compiler Performance by Over 75%"](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/increasing-compiler-speed-by-over-75/240158941), by Walter Bright. Of course, a compiler is a specialized problem domain, and Walter Bright is probably one of the top compiler developers alive, so techniques that work for his problem domain shouldn't be blindly applied elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

> - the resulting program will run on a modern OS (or in this case, that collects memory from dead processes)
>
> I am very tempted to just use raw pointers, never free the memory taken by those objects and let the OS do its cleanup after the process exits.

If you take this approach, then anyone who uses your library and then uses `valgrind` to try to detect memory leaks in their program will report massive leaks coming from your library and complain to you about it, so if I were you I definitely would not do this.

Comment: I am aware of this, but I can still provide valgrind suppressions for these objects, so it should still be usable.

Comment: well I mean ultimately if its up to you, but if all of my libraries provided valgrind suppression files and I had to track them all down and figure out how to integrate them all when I use them I would probably be a bit annoyed. I mean if you just take all the statically allocated raw pointers, and make them `std::unique_ptr`, it should at least guarantee that the memory is freed when the program ends normally, with minimal overhead. it's still not as good as carefully freeing the memory when you don't need it but its at least a little better wrt valgrind

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` would have been OK if it were not for the fact that the user may request an instance of these objects, and that some of the objects themselves reference (without owning) other of their kind.

Comment: Ultimately, I agree that this will probably be too great of a hassle, but I'm waiting for a bit more answers and thoughts before choosing what seems best :)

Comment: so i mean, you could use std::unique_ptr for the "owning" pointers, and raw pointers for the "non-owning" pointers. if you want you can also give the user a unique_ptr to the object, or provide the user with raw pointers but give them a "free_object" function which they are required to call. (then presumably they will put it in unique_ptr or something with a custom deleter that calls your function). that's good e.g. if someone compiles your library with mingw and gives it to someone with msvc, then it won't crash on free when they try to free an object from the lib.

Comment: As long as the memory is still reachable (and it sounds like it would be), then Valgrind shouldn't complain, should it?

Comment: @JoshKelley: You know, you might be right. I have definitely seen cases in code where e.g., someone is using something like `std::map<std::string, static_init_object*>` at file scope to hold some statically initialized registry, and then what happens is the map gets destroyed at program end and all those pointers are reported as leaks by valgrind. but maybe if you just have `static_init_object * ptr` it doesn't actually get "deallocated" like a stack variable so at program end it doesn't look like a leak? i guess i should experiment to find out, i'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a library then you should provide a cleanup function that frees all memory that you allocated.

A practical example of why this is useful is if a Windows DLL uses your library. When the library is loaded, static data is initialized. When the library is unloaded, static data is cleared.  If your library has some global pointers to memory that is never freed, then load-unload cycles of the DLL will leak memory.

Comment: OpenSSL has this same bug. I submitted a patch to add a clean-up function once and it got rejected because someone said that those things should never be `free`d ... go figure

Answer (score 1):

If your ownership and lifetimes are clear  I suggest you use `unique_ptr` for the owning pointers and raw pointers for the non-owning pointers. It should be less complex than `shared_ptr` and  `weak_ptr` whilst still managing memory automatically.

I don't think not managing memory at all is an option.  But I think using smart pointers to express ownership is not just about good memory management it also makes code easier to reason about.

Answer (score 1):

If the objects are all of the same type, then rather than allocating each one independently, you could just put them all into a `vector` and have them refer to each other by index number instead of using pointers.  The vector's built-in memory management takes care of allocating space as needed, and when you're done with the objects, you can just destroy the vector to deallocate them all at once.  (Note that `vector::clear()` doesn't actually free the memory, though it does make it available to store a new set of objects in the vector.)

If your objects aren't all the same type, you'll want to look into the more general concept of [region-based memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management).  As above, the idea is that you can allocate all your objects in a relatively small number of memory chunks (possibly just one), which can be freed later without having to track all the
individual objects allocated within.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of future maintenance work. Suppose your code needs to be broken up or other stuff done after it. In this case you're opening yourself up to leaks or being a resource hog later down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up (or being able to do s) is good. It may seem obvious now that an application should work with a single structured binary dataset throughout its entire lifetime, but you'll start kicking yourself once you realize you need to write an application that needs to reset half-way through and start over with another dataset.

(a related thing that's easy to overlook is that an application may need to work with two completely independent datasets at the same time, so try not to design your library to exclude that use case!)

---

That said, I think you may be focusing too much on the extremes. Code that shouldn't participate in memory management can use raw pointers, and this is reasonable when there is no risk of these pointers outliving your structured dataset in memory.

However, that doesn't mean that code that *does* participate in memory management needs to use raw pointers too. You can use smart pointers to manage your data structures even if you are passing raw pointers out to the user.

That aside, keep in mind that, in my experience, pointers are usually the wrong semantics — usually, most use cases are most natural with *reference* or *value* semantics, which means you should be passing around raw *references*, or passing around lightweight wrapper class that have reference or value semantics, but are implemented as containing a pointer to the actual data. Or even as a copy of the actual data if appropriate.